# Some doubts about this simple INNER JOIN query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I have the following doubt about this simple **INNER JOIN** query.

I have these two tables that have to be joined togheter:

The first table is named **VulnerabilityFix** and contains the following columns:

> Id:    int identity
>
> FixName:     varchar
>
> Vendor:    varchar
>
> Title:     varchar
>
> Version:     varchar

The second table is named **VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityFix** (this bind the previous table to another table, but this is not important at this time) and contains the following columns:

> VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId:    int
>
> VulnerabilityFixId:     int

Now, on my DB the **VulnerabilityFix** table contains only an empty record (this record have an id but all the other fields are empty\null), infact if I perform a select *, I obtain:

```
select * from VulnerabilityFix

Id  FixName Vendor  Title   Version

1
```

Into the **VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityFix** I have something like this:

```
select * from VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityFix

VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId      VulnerabilityFixId

78385                             1

78386                             1

....................................................
....................................................
....................................................
78398                             1
```

Ok, so I want JOIN toghert these 2 table in in such a way that passing the value of the **VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId** field of the **VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityFix** table, I obtain all the related record in the **VulnerabilityFix** table.

So in this case I aspect to retrieve the previous only record that having an id (having a value equal to 1) and all the other fields are empty\null.

So my query is:

```
SELECT VF.* FROM VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityFix VAD_VF
            INNER JOIN VulnerabilityFix VF ON VAD_VF.VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId = VF.Id
            WHERE VAD_VF.VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId = 1
```

The problem is that when I execute this query I obtain an empty set of records and not the unique record that I expetc to obtain.

Why? What am I missing?

Tnx

Comment: Looking at the sample data, I do not see a record in VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityFix table with VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId = 1.

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your query should be more like:

```
SELECT VF.* FROM VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityFix VAD_VF
            INNER JOIN VulnerabilityFix VF ON VAD_VF.VulnerabilityFixId = VF.Id
            WHERE VAD_VF.VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId = 78385
```

That is, you are using the wrong column at your ON condition since `VulnerabilityFixId` seems to be the foreign key over `VulnerabilityFix.Id` and not `VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId`.

On the other hand, I can't see any `VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityFix.VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId` with value 1 in you data set (where condition)

Comment: i would omit the where entirely